# Axios request doesn't resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm trying to create on a function that makes an axios request to a certain API and returns the data it gets back. I understand it has to be asynchronous, and I'm trying to build the function like that in NodeJS, but it keeps giving me a "promise pending" and doesn't return the data. It will do a console log, but I need to get the data returned whenever I call this function. The code I'm working with:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function simple() {
    const url = 'https://api.somerandomfakeurl.com/'

    return getData(url)
}

async function getData(url){
    const data = await axios(url).then(response => { return response })

    return data
}
```

So when I call on the simple() function, I want to get the response data. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `getData` returns a promise, and so will therefore `simple`. No way around that.

Comment: @Andy Welcome but you misunderstand async await. An async function always return a promise. You would need to handle that or make your other function Async, but that then means that function is returning a promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.

Comment: `const myData = await simple()` or `simple().then(myData => ...)`

Comment: You nee do make simple an `async` function: `export default async function simple() {` and then `await` the `getData()` function call: `return await getData(url)`

Comment: FYI: `response => { return response }` can just be `response => response.data`.

Comment: @a1300 That still means `simple` returns a promise, because *it* is `async`…

Comment: @deceze yes, `async` all the way :) Would you return `getData(url)` without `await`? It is a taste issue isn't it?

Comment: @a1300 No big difference either way.